# django-paypal does not receive signals

Tags: python, django, paypal, signals

I have a sandbox PAYPAL area,
My language is python - Django and I use django-paypal
ipn tes on my server works but
when someone try to buy something, after paypal process in sandbox I don't receive signal and in my paypal_ipn I don't see the transaction.
So the problem is that I don't receive the signal.
This is my signal code in models.py

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
    code = sender.item_number
    type, number_product, pagamento_corso_id = code.split('_')
    obj = get_object_or_404(PagamentoCorso, int(pagamento_corso_id))
    obj.pagamento = True
    obj.save()

payment_was_successful.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

Please help me because is 7 days... and I'm very frustrated! :-)

Comment: Several ideas come to mind:

1) Have you set a notify/return url on your paypal form?

2) Are you behind a firewall and is the port forwarded correctly?

3) Is the form submitting to the paypal sandbox server or the real one?

4) Are you getting a http request from paypal at all?

Comment: Hi... finally I find the problem. Only now I see that I don't send notify_url for intercept return signals :-) Thanks Pyeleven

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the Paypal Test Tools to send fake notifactions to your notify url. That might make it easier to debug.

http://www.friendly-stranger.com/pictures/paypal.jpg

What you can also do is run the tests that come with django-paypal. It should be something like

```
python manage.py test paypal
```

You can also take a look at the test code and create your own tests to debug your problem.

If you still can't figure it out post your url configuration and the view that passes the IPN form to the template.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I could see from access logs that PayPal *is* accessing my payment notification URL, and the requests are 200 OK, but no signals triggered on Django side.

Turned out that payments had "Pending" status instead of "Completed" (and I wasn't listening on `paypal.standard.ipn.signals.payment_was_flagged` signal).

The reason my payments were flagged, was incorrect `settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL` and incorrect `paypal_dict["business"]` email addresses. Exact same issue [as for this guy](http://jayngo.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-django-paypal.html).

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you look at the PayPalIPN table in the Django Admin view, the `Flag info` column will show errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was trivial - I've added the signal handler code to `views.py` which is not loaded automatically so the handler was never really used and connected to the signal. The simplest but ugly solution is to move them to `models.py`, recommended is to use Django's [ready()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method.